# PostgreSQL - check for empty list

Tags: django, postgresql

I've written application in Django and tested it using SQLite. But now in production I want to use PostgreSQL and  there's problem, because calling:

```
empty_list = []
Foo.objects.exclude(pk__in=empty_list).delete()
```

raises ProgrammingError (bad query - postgres doesn't accept in queries empty `IN ()` )

I don't want to rewrite all code and wrap all `exclude`s and `filter`s in method that checks for empty list. I also don't want to write thousand of `if`s or modify Django code. Is there any elegant solution to solve this?

Comment: *"I've written application in Django and tested it using SQLite. But now in production I want to use PostgreSQL ..."*. Big mistake. You weren't testing your application as you'll really use it. *Always* test on an environment that matches what you'll deploy to for real. In this case, if Django generated that query as `= ANY (ARRAY[])` it'd be OK, but there's no way to get Pg to accept `IN ()`.

Comment: You didn't understand, I want to use it in production so NOW I'm testing if it's behaving correctly. Also - I don't want to make Pg accept `IN()`, but in "some way" alter Django/my app behavior to not generate it.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I found this: http://www.tryolabs.com/Blog/2013/07/05/run-time-method-patching-python/

It's simple, just write sth like this:

```
from django.db.models import QuerySet


def new_exclude(self, *args, **kwargs):
    kw = dict()
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        if is_not_empty_list(value) and is_not_empty_queryset(value): #other checks?
           kw[key] = value

    if len(kw):
        return old_exclude(self, *args, **kw)
    else:
        return self

old_exclude = QuerySet.exclude
QuerySet.exclude = new_exclude
```

But personally I don't like this solution, so I won't accept it and I'm waiting for better one.